# How can I set the value of a property on a attribute on a object?

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

I am trying to set the value of a property on an attribute on a class.

```
[FooAttr(ThePropertyIWantToSet=null)]
public class Foo
{
}

Foo theFoo = new Foo();
theFoo.SetAttributeProperty<FooAttrAttribute>("ThePropertyIWantToSet", theValueIWantToSet);
```

This is the SetAttributeProperty extension method I have written. It compiles and runs but it doesn't seem to be setting the property.

```
public static void SetAttributeProperty<T>(this object instance, string fieldName, object value) where T : Attribute
{
    var attr = instance.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof (T), false).FirstOrDefault();

    PropertyInfo pi = attr.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty);
    pi.SetValue(attr, value, null);
}
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Are you trying to set default value to a property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no idea whether this is even possible, but it's not how attributes are meant to be used. I don't know that there are any guarantees around how and when attribute instances are created. For example, it's quite possible that each time you *ask* a type or member for its attributes, they're deserialized from the metadata again.

Basically I think you should *treat* attributes as immutable after compilation, even if they have properties with setters.

EDIT: This short but complete program seems to indicate that `Type.GetCustomAttributes` can indeed create a new instance each time you call it:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.All)]
class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[Foo]
class Bar
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var attr = typeof(Bar).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FooAttribute), true)[0];
        var attr2 = typeof(Bar).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(FooAttribute), true)[0];
        Console.WriteLine(attr == attr2); // Prints False
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible using PostSharp or some other frameworks which will do some kind of injection.

Comment: @Yuriy: It's not clear exactly what you mean... are you disagreeing with me or agreeing with me? If you're disagreeing, can you cite any documentation which suggests that if you retrieve the same attribute twice from a type, it's guaranteed to return two references to the same object?

Comment: From bitter experience, I know you *can* get different instances

Comment: @Marc: Have just come up with an example showing exactly that :)

Comment: @Jon my mistake, I was under the impression he was trying to do something else.

Comment: That's a shame. I have a validator attribute which uses a service which is Property injected at runtime using my IOC container. However. for unit testing the validation I just wanted to inject a mocked service. Sounds like it can't be done

Comment: @James: I'd have to know more about what exactly the IOC container is doing... but are you sure it's actually changing the property of the *attribute* rather than setting a property in your object itself using the attribute to describe which property to set?

Comment: Hi Jon, no it's definitely setting the property on the attribute. I'm using the same pattern illustrated in the following article http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/40/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-2---part-3--custom-dataannotation-validationattributes

Comment: @James: I believe the point is that the validator there is hanging on to the attribute after populating it - it's *not* then asking the type/member/whatever for the attribute again.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. I'll try and find another way to test it

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that at runtime is to model attributes at runtime rather than reflection. Luckily `TypeDescriptor` does this already. So you should find that if you only use `TypeDescriptor` to get the attribute, then `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(...)` should do the job of assigning a new attribute at runtime;

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(TargetType),
    new Attribute[] {yourAttribWithNewValue});
```

However, this only works if the code consuming the attribute uses `TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(...)`.